# How can I exit my current project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, how can I exit the current project and load another?  Something like reloading?

i.e when i'm executiing my project(window application) i need to close the current exe and load another instance of the exe file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

File --> Close Project...
File --> Open Project

Comment: i.e when i'm executiing my project(window application) i need to close the current exe and load another instance of the exe file.

Comment: Stop debugging and start debugging?

Comment: **Ctrl+Shift+F5**

Comment: This command doesn't seem to exist now, either that or it's context sensitive and cloned GIT repos don't count

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the restart action.

View|Toolbars|Debug will show you the toolbar; the square blue icon with an arrow pointing left is what you're after.

On my system the keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+F5.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open another project.  Visual Studio will automatically close the current project when opening a new one.

I'm still not entirely sure that's what you're asking for though.  Here are a couple of related actions and the way to achieve them

- Unload project: Right Click and select "Unload"
- Remove project from solution: Right click and select "Remove"
- Close Solution: Right click on the solution and select "Close"

Comment: i.e when i'm executiing my project(window application) i need to close the current exe and load another instance of the exe file.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to restart the program currently being debugged, then use the command "**Debug -> Restart**" or press "**Ctrl+Shift+F5**".